# Missing cursor on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, mouse-cursor

A family member has a laptop with Windows 10, and the cursor has completely vanished. It's present at the login screen, and gone immediately after. They usually use a wired USB mouse, but the trackpad is doing nothing as well. The laptop does not have a touch screen, so we have no way of interacting with things normally.

Most solutions online don't exactly match this issue, or suggest fixes that require the use of a cursor, so we're a bit stuck. Hoping someone can suggest a keyboard-only fix that we haven't tried.

**EDIT** Additional troubleshooting

---

What we've tried so far, after extensive googling and keyboard-only navigation as suggested below:

- Turning it off and on again (a few times)
- Pressing all function keys to re-enable the cursor (fn+F1 ... +F12)
- Disconnecting the mouse and reconnecting it
- Testing the mouse on a different computer (it works fine)
- Connecting a different mouse
- Connecting either mouse (old or new) to a different USB port
- Checking for a physical "disable cursor" switch near the trackpad or on the side (there is none)
- Alt-tab in case the cursor is captured by a background application
- Opening task manager (ctrl-shift-esc) to try to free the cursor
- Flailing mouse and trackpad wildly in frustration
- Windows is up-to-date, no updates available
- Device manager recognized both mouse and trackpad, and says they're working properly
- Alt-tab and task manager don't show any open apps after logging in - nothing to break the cursor out of.
- Opened the old mouse control panel and enabled the "locate my cursor when I press ctrl". A circle pings at the center of the screen, and does not change after mouse interaction.
- Rebooting in safe mode made no difference - cursor still missing, ctrl pings at the center of the screen.
- Checked the cursor to make sure nobody had swapped out the graphic for an invisible one - changing to a few different system ones made no differe. Ctrl still pings at center of screen.
- No unknown scripts or apps in the startup registry

---

What the issue isn't:

- Cursur is laggy or frozen. **It is not visible anywhere on the screen.**
- Cursor only disappears in some apps, or while typing. **It is gone completely at all times.**
- Deprecated / end-of-life hardware. **Laptop was purchased new early 2021, less than 4 months ago.**
- Laptop is frozen. **Laptop still responds to keyboard input.**
- Cursor is hidden in a corner. **We checked, a lot.**
- Cursor is caught on a different display. **No other displays connected.**

Comment: Restart in Safe Mode and then see if you can resolve the issues in Safe Mode.  Also, if you can with keystrokes, make a new test User, make it a member of Administrators and try the new user. It could be a damaged User Profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what the issue was - but booting into safe mode and running startup repair got the mouse working again. Booting into the ASUS diagnostic mode and performing the trackpad diagnostic got the trackpad working again.

Answer (score 1):

> It's present at the login screen, and gone immediately after.

This sounds like it's caused by a user-level preference.

- Check within 'main.cpl' (described below) whether the cursor theme hasn't been changed to a completely blank one as a prank.
- Check Task Manager's "Startup" tab for any suspicious apps. Try to disable them all and reboot. (If that helped, then re-enable one by one until you find the cause.)

> Most solutions online don't exactly match this issue, or suggest fixes that require the use of a cursor, so we're a bit stuck. Hoping someone can suggest a keyboard-only fix that we haven't tried.

> What we're not able to try, because it requires cursor interaction:
>
> - Checking for windows updates
> - Checking the device manager to see if the mouse and trackpad are recognized

I do want to point out that *nearly all* things in Windows can be interacted with using entirely just the keyboard, without needing mouse or touch-screen input at all. You mostly use Tab and arrow keys to do it.

- **Device Manager:** Press <kbd>⊞Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, input `devmgmt.msc`.

  Alternatively, as of Windows 10, there is the <kbd>⊞Win</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> menu (aka "right-click Start" menu) which offers direct access to <kbd>M</kbd> Device Manager.

  It's also findable by opening <kbd>⊞Win</kbd> *Start* and typing "device manager" into the Start menu.

  - When the Device Manager opens, use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus the device tree, then arrow keys to navigate through the tree. Either the <kbd>→ Right</kbd> arrow or the <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> will expand a collapsed subtree.
  - Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will "double-click" an item, in this case opening its Properties window. If necessary you can use either <kbd>≣Menu</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> to access the "right-click" menu of an item.
  - Within the Properties window, you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PgDn</kbd> to switch tabs. Then use regular <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate to a particular button, <kbd>Space</kbd> to "click" it.
  - You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>*letter*</kbd> to directly activate whatever button has an underlined letter in its text. The underlines may be hidden at first, but will show up when holding Alt. This also goes for the menu at the top of the Device Manager window.
  - For example, in the main window, use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>V</kbd> (or just <kbd>Alt</kbd> followed by arrow keys) to activate the "Devices by connection" view, which can sometimes be more informative, e.g. if it happens to show everything underneath a particular USB controller as unrecognized.
- **Old "Mouse" control panel:** Press <kbd>⊞Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, input `main.cpl`.

  Navigable using Tab, Ctrl+Tab, etc. as described above.

  - I would in particular suggest going to the "Pointer" tab and trying to change the cursor appearance scheme. Try selecting "(None)" for the old-style unthemed cursor (which should *always* work), or "Windows Default" for the modern-style one.

    After you've tabbed to the schemes drop-down list, Up/Down arrows will work, but <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>↓Down</kbd> will also expand the list. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to 'Apply' changes.
  - I'd also suggest going to the "Options" tab and enabling "Show location of pointer..." – either by tabbing around as described earlier, or by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to activate the checkbox then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to 'Apply' if you are on English Windows.

    With this option active, hit just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> alone to make Windows show a circle animation around where the pointer is *supposed* to be.
- **Command Prompt:** <kbd>⊞Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, `cmd` (or just find it through Search).

  - If you need to run 'cmd' with Administrator rights – hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> while pressing Enter. (Works both in *Run* and in search results.)
- **Windows updates:** Press <kbd>⊞Win</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to open *Settings*. You can also directly open any Settings section through Windows Search.

  - The Windows 10 settings app is UWP, so almost everything is keyboardable using exclusively just <kbd>Tab</kbd> and arrow-keys. (No Alt+letter hotkeys though.) The "Back" button is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd>.
- **Switching apps:**

  - Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between windows, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> to close the current window.
  - Use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to open the window control menu (for move/resize). As of Windows Vista you can also use <kbd>⊞Win</kbd><kbd>↑Up</kbd> and <kbd>⊞Win</kbd><kbd>↓Down</kbd> to (un)maximize.
- **Websites:**

  - If you want to select and copy text from a website (such as a long command), press <kbd>F7</kbd> to enable "Caret mode".
- **MouseKeys:** In case you still need to click on something that really cannot be Tab'd to.

  - Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>NumLock</kbd> to activate the "[MouseKeys](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-mouse-keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer-9e0c72c8-b882-7918-8e7b-391fd62adf33)" feature.

    (You can later disable it through *Settings → Ease of Access*.)
  - Now whenever Num Lock is enabled, the numpad digit keys will move the cursor around (slowly but with acceleration), <kbd>NumPad /</kbd> or <kbd>NumPad -</kbd> (minus) will choose the left/right mouse button respectively, <kbd>NumPad 5</kbd> will click.

  This can be really annoying to use on smaller laptops which do not have a dedicated numpad, but it still kind of works.

*(This edit brought to you by Ctrl+Enter.)*

Comment: Now *this* is some useful information! I'll give these a try and see if we can't make progress.

Comment: This information got me to a solution - I'd upvote twice if I could. Cheers!